# How to display custom value for enum in Swagger UI in Java?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger-ui

I need to display custom value for enum in my swagger-ui in java.
I have an enum (Gender) in my DTO. The swagger UI displays a dropdown as needed but the display text and option values are also same.

Swagger UI output below:

```
 <select id="mgender0.6152790512895818" name="gender" class="parameter ">
      <option value="" selected=""></option>
      <option value="Female"> Female  </option>
      <option value="Male"> Male  </option>
  </select>
```

As you can see, the value also has "Female" and "Male". That should be "M" and "F" instead of full text.

Here is my Java Enum

```
public enum Gender {
    F("Female"), M("Male");

    private String displayValue;

    private Gender(String displayValue) {
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return displayValue;
    }

    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return displayValue;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Expected output in swagger is:

```
    <select id="mgender0.6152790512895818" name="gender" class="parameter ">
      <option value="" selected=""></option>
      <option value="F"> Female  </option>
      <option value="M"> Male  </option>
  </select>
```

Please help me regarding the same. I've tried @APIModel attribute but there must be something wrong with what am doing as its not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider implementing your own [ParameterBuilderPlugin](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/current/springfox/documentation/spi/service/ParameterBuilderPlugin.html).